# how to convert List<List<String>> into hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList which stores both key & value in each row (e.g 1st row will have no,firstname,lastname,age and 2nd row will have 1,xxx,yyy,23 and 3rd row will have 2,aaa,bbb,24 and so on). First row have all the keys and the remaining rows will have the values.
I want to convert this into hashmap (e.g the keyshould be firstname and the values should be xxx,aaa).
Is there a way to do this??

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you done so far?

Comment: In which format do you expect the entries? A List of HashMaps, each containing a row's key-value-association or one HashMap with a list of values behind a key?

Answer (score 0):

Given that a `List<List<String>>` variable is extensible in both ways (e.g. you can make the list longer, but you can also make the list in the list longer), and given that a `HashMap` basically has fixed dimensions (one key goes to one value, not multiple), the only way to do this is by creating a new object containing the list data and have the key point to this object.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list of HashMaps, meaning that for each of your value rows, you get a key-value structure:

```
static List<HashMap<String, String>> listToMap(List<List<String>> lst){
  List<HashMap<String, String>> lmap = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> keys = lst.get(0);
  for(int row=1;row<lst.size();row++){
    List<String> currentRow = lst.get(row);
    HashMap<String, String> kvRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i=0;i<keys.size();i++){
      kvRow.put(keys.get(i), currentRow.get(i));
    }
    lmap.add(kvRow);
  }
  return lmap;
}
```

If you run this with your sample data...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<List<String>> lst = new ArrayList<>(3);
  lst.add(Arrays.asList("no","firstname","lastname","age"));
  lst.add(Arrays.asList("1","xxx","yyy","23"));
  lst.add(Arrays.asList("2","aaa","bbb","24"));
  System.out.println(listToMap(lst));
}
```

it prints

```
[{no=1, age=23, lastname=yyy, firstname=xxx}, {no=2, age=24, lastname=bbb, firstname=aaa}]
```

Is this the way you want it? This code assumes that all your value rows have at least as many values as the "keys"-row.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following list defined somewhere in scope:

```
List<List<String>> keyValueList;
```

First, poll the list to get the headers out.

```
List<String> headers = keyValueList.get(0);
```

Then, you can use a ListIterator to iterate over all of the values.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(headers.size());
ListIterator<List<String>> valueLists = keyValueList.listIterator(1);

while(valueLists.hasNext()){
    Iterator<String> values = valueLists.next().iterator();
    Iterator<String> keys = headers.iterator();
    myMap.put(keys.next(), values.next());
}
```

And then you're done.

Comment: Each value list overwrites the previous values in the map.

Answer (score -2):

Because you're using ArrayLists, which are ordered, you may want to use an ordered map like LinkedHashMap which would preserve the order that you insert them.

```
List<List<String>> inputList;
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
int nEntries = inputList.get(0).size();

String thisKey;
List<String> thisList;

for(int index = 0; i < nEntries; i++){ //iterate over all column indexes

    for(List<String> thisRow:inputList){
        //if this is the first row, this is our key.
        if(inputList.indexOf(thisRow) == 0){
            thisKey = thisRow.get(index);
            thisList.clear();
        }
        else{
            thisList.add(thisRow.get(index);
        }
    }
    map.put(thisKey,thisList);

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer... And this is not correct as well... He doesn't need an ordered map here...